# How can I recreate the number lines underneath the graph in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2

[here is the number lines i am trying to recreate - it includes the min, median, and max values of ages for juveniles, females, and males.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SQTz7.png)

```
original_plot <- ggplot(turtle2011, aes(x = Zage1, y = Agglut, shape = Sex)) +
geom_point() +
geom_smooth(method = "lm", se = FALSE, color = "red") +  # Add regression line
labs(x = "Zage", y = "Natural Antibodies") +  # Set axis labels
scale_shape_manual(values = c(1, 17, 15)) +  # Customize shapes for each sex
theme_minimal()  # Set plot theme
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! You could create a second plot and combine it with main plot using e.g. `patchwork` or `cowplot` or ... . For more help please provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) including a snippet of your data best shared using `dput()` or using some fake data or using a built-in dataset.